# How to use 3 predetermined words in user's input to print a predetermined response

Tags: python, loops, input

This would work if all 3 words were necessary, but it prints: *"X is a box"* when 'A','B','D' is the input. I want 'A','B','D' to only print: *"X is a triangle"*, and *"X is a box"* to only print when 'A''B''C' is the input.

```
while True:
    begin = input('prompt  ')
    if 'A' and 'B' and 'C' in begin:
        answer = ('\n X is a box')
        print(answer)
        continue

    elif 'A' and 'C' and 'D' in begin:
        answer = ('\n X is a circle')
        print(answer)
        continue

    elif 'A' and 'B' and 'D' in begin:
        answer = ('\n X is a triangle')
        print(answer)
        continue

    elif '' in begin:
        print('not a shape')
```

It's a simplified version of a game I'm creating for a beginner's project. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Still figuring out this sight. Why did the first two lines of my code example get converted to line text?

Comment: You either need to indent it correctly it or to enclose it within proper characters. I've suggested an adit to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for making it look as I intended! Do you know how I can require all 3 letters to return answer instead of just 1 or 2?

Comment: Doesn't anyone know the answer to this problem?

Comment: Thanks again for fixing my code example . It helped a lot I'm sure..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to S/O. Note that `in` simply checks if any of the chars in question is in the variable `begin`. To achieve your intended functionality, change it as follows

```
while True:
    begin = input('prompt  ')
    if "'A','B','C'" == begin:
        answer = ('\n X is a box')
        print(answer)
        continue

    elif "'A','C','D'" == begin:
        answer = ('\n X is a circle')
        print(answer)
        continue

    elif "'A','B','D'" == begin:
        answer = ('\n X is a triangle')
        print(answer)
        continue

    elif '' in begin:
        print('not a shape')
```

Your input must match any of the following:

1. 'A','B','C'
2. 'A','C','D'
3. 'A','B','D'

**Update:**

The current code cannot accommodate your new problem. To filter out unnecessary words follow the method below.

The split method will be useful in ignoring unnecessary words, see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)

```
while True:
    begin = input('prompt  ')
    beginList = begin.split()
    if 'A' in beginList and 'B' in beginList and 'C' in beginList:
        answer = ('\n X is a box')
        print(answer)
        continue
```

As you can see, if you pass in the input `"A who B when XXX C"` the if will execute and print `X is a box`. Apply the same logic to other parts of the conditonal statements and should solve your problem.

Comment: Thankyou for your help. Now, can we take this a step further and let the input contain various words between the A, B, and D, that won't interfere with the function? As is,  it skips over A,B,D when anything is added to the A,B,D input other than just A,B, and D.

Comment: Can you elaborate exactly what you mean so that I don't misunderstand it. Ideally with an example and you can update that to the question.

Comment: Ok. So it's a mystery game where the user's input questions contain the character they're asking(A), a handful of "when, where, etc." words(B), and words of interest to the mystery "victim, suspect, etc."(C). I need to filter those three words out of the input question to return a specific answer(character's prerecorded response) to the user(detective). One extra word other than A,B,D(character, 'who', 'motive') causes it to skip to elif '' in begin:

Comment: doesn't anyone know the answer to this problem?

Comment: oops, just now saw the solution .Thankyou! What a relief!

Comment: I am really, really grateful for your help. I spent days trying to figure this out. My beginner's motivation was really suffering until you came along. I f only I could repay you somehow...

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign. Thanks